# How to clean molten plastic from a pizza stone?

Tags: oven, cleaning, electric-stoves, pizza-stone

I have a pizza stone, which has molten plastic on it (it touched the edge of a plastic chopping board briefly, while hot). I cleaned as best as I could with water, but when I put it in the oven it fumes very strongly.

My idea was to try to burn the plastic off in the oven, but oven doesn't appear to have the pyrolyze function or programme.

Should I try and pyrolyze the stone in the oven anyway, even though my oven doesn't have a specific pyrolyze function? Is it safe?

What program should I set and for how long?

This is my stove: https://manualscollection.com/?fid=9dc6ab1d73e58b75a2c28e6625e3b9db&read=online&page=28

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1484, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/83564, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10661

Comment: Hi, your original question was a bit strange. It asked about heating your stone, despite having no "pyrolize" option (I assume you mean the same function that is widely known in the US as self-clean). It was not clear what you wanted to achieve by heating it, if you thought that you have to do that to clean it, cure it, or maybe you just wanted to bake on that setting and were put off by fumes. Apparently the plastic came later. We already have questions on cleaning and curing pizza stones as well as fumes, so instead of closing as duplicate, I reworded your question  to be about the plastic.

Comment: My real question is about whether it is safe to heat-clean with an oven, not designed to heat-clean (or self clean). But the plastic part is important too, maybe even more important.

Comment: I assume you've already scraped off everything you can, with your worst sharp kitchen knife, possibly while warm?

Comment: I ended up scraping everything and just doing the heat clean, it worked out, at some point it stopped smoking.

Comment: Do you have an outdoor (preferably gas) grill. I would put the pizza stone in the grill on high heat for 45 minutes to an hour...

Comment: @CosCallis I have an electric outdoor grill, I was thinking about that! But I thought, that maybe it wouldn't heat evenly and would end up cracking the stone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone interested: I ended up scraping the stone with a butter knife and some steel wool, removing all visible plastic, after which I put it in the oven and heated it up to about 275°C. After about an hour it stopped fuming, and from what I can tell there was not much left on it, although it was still kind of black, but not as black as it was when I put it in the oven.

There were no problems with the oven, as for the plastic, I am still not sure if there isn't some plastic in the pores of the stone, but since it is not fuming I guess that most of it is gone. I will use the bottom side of the stone in the future and hope not to poison myself with plastic.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked, I was going to suggest using a paint scraper.

Comment: @JoC I also used a stove scraper, but the knife + wool steel worked better.

Comment: Next time you can go with enamel remover acetone, too

Answer (score 1):

Pyrolysation is the only way to clean melted plastic from the stone. First you scrape all the bulk plastic, scrape and put under cold water, and remove it with ease, and then to remove residue from the stone, use 500°F pyrolyse on both heaters, open the door from time to time to vent the oven.